# Pulling raw events data from Google analytics without BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Is it possible to collect raw events data by just using Google Analytics reporting/data API? There is a way to get the raw events by linking it to BigQuery, but can we do it without involving BigQuery (as GCP resource footprint).